# ReadComplete() called twice

Tags: netty

Note: This question was posted in the past but the solution is not working today using ChannelOption.MAX_MESSAGES_PER_READ. Also, the option is deprecated.

Note: As a reminder .. I am new with Netty.

Using Netty 4.1.51, when I stimulate the following code with 'curl -v http://localhost:8080/', the console output of my program shows:

```
Server listening on 8080
Read
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
Accept: */*

ReadComplete
Write Hello
flush
ReadComplete
Write Hello
flush
```

The handler read() method is called once, the readComplete() method is called twice, yet, curl seems happy about the exchange.

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying ::1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 ok
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 5
<
Hello* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I can't seem to understand whats going on .. has anyone encountered this problem lately ?

Shouldn't readComplete() occur once after one or more reads ?

Thanks to all with the spare time to look at this.

-jmr

---

```
private static void bootstrap1() {

    int port = 8080;
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();

    bootstrap
        .group(group)
        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
        .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>()
        {
            @Override protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) 
            throws Exception 
            {
                ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                pipeline.addLast("out", new OutHandler());
                pipeline.addLast("in", new InHandler());
            }
        });
    
    ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
    future.addListener((ChannelFutureListener) (ChannelFuture future1) -> 
    {
        if (future1.isSuccess()) {
            pr("Server listening on " + port);
        } else {
            future1.cause().printStackTrace();
        }
    });        
}

private static class InHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        pr("Read");
        if (msg instanceof ByteBuf) {
            ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
            pr("" + buf.readCharSequence(buf.readableBytes(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
        }
        ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
    }
    
    @Override public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) 
            throws Exception 
    {
        pr("ReadComplete");
        ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.buffer();
        buf.writeCharSequence("Hello", Charset.defaultCharset());
        ctx.writeAndFlush(buf);
        ctx.fireChannelReadComplete();
    }
}

private static class OutHandler extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {
    
    @Override public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, 
            ChannelPromise promise) 
            throws Exception 
    {
        ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
        pr("Write " + in.getCharSequence(0, in.readableBytes(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
        
        ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.buffer();
        buf.writeCharSequence("HTTP/1.1 200 ok\r\n", Charset.defaultCharset());
        buf.writeCharSequence("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n", Charset.defaultCharset());
        buf.writeCharSequence("Content-Length: 5\r\n\r\n", Charset.defaultCharset());
        buf.writeCharSequence(in.readCharSequence(5, Charset.defaultCharset()), Charset.defaultCharset());
        in.release();
        ctx.write(buf);
    }
    
    @Override public void flush(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) 
            throws Exception 
    {
        pr("flush");
        ctx.flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `channelReadComplete` being called twice, you're also writing your HTTP response twice, indicated by the duplicate "Write Hello" log message.

`channelReadComplete` is being called twice because auto-read is turned on (which happens by default). To turn that off and trigger an initial read only, you could amend your `ChannelInitializer` as follows:

```
.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>()
{
    @Override protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch)
        throws Exception
    { 
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast("out", new OutHandler());
        pipeline.addLast("in", new InHandler());
        ch.config().setAutoRead(false);
        ch.read();
    }
});
```

Having said all that, `channelReadComplete` isn't really the right place to be creating and sending your response. In your case, doing so is causing the double-send of the response. curl may be ok with that but it's not what you want. The `channelRead` method is a better place for sending a response once you've gathered a complete request.

For a reference echo server, have a look here: https://github.com/normanmaurer/netty-in-action/tree/2.0-SNAPSHOT/chapter2/Server/src/main/java/nia/chapter2/echoserver

I highly recommend the NIA book to get you pointed in the right direction on all things netty.